# Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

```
@RequestMapping("/twitter")
public ModelAndView twitter(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String ConsumerKey="WZIBZVr1H6nst0D**********";
    String ConsumerSecret="chj82ljAXNmO544cUAEkSNDon3eTm3Bn200qOEK7**********";
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey(ConsumerKey)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(ConsumerSecret);

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();


    RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("userToken",requestToken.getToken());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("userSecretToken",requestToken.getTokenSecret());


    System.out.println("requestToken.getToken() ====> "+requestToken.getToken());
    System.out.println("requestToken.getTokenSecret() ====> "+requestToken.getTokenSecret());

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
}

@RequestMapping("/favList")
public String favList(HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap model) throws Exception {

    String ConsumerKey="WZIBZVr1H6nst0D**********";
    String ConsumerSecret="chj82ljAXNmO544cUAEkSNDon3eTm3Bn200qOEK7**********";
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey(ConsumerKey)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(ConsumerSecret);

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    String userToken = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("userToken");

    String oauthToken = (String)request.getParameter("oauth_token");
    String oauthVerifier = (String)request.getParameter("oauth_verifier");

    System.out.println("oauthToken ====> "+oauthToken);
    System.out.println("oauthVerifier ====> "+oauthVerifier);
    AccessToken accessToken=null;

    if(userToken =="" || userToken ==null){
        return "redirect:/twitter.do";
    }

    if(userToken.equals(oauthToken)){

        try{

            accessToken= twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(oauthToken,oauthVerifier);

        }catch(TwitterException e){

        }
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
        List<Status> statuses =null;
        Paging page = new Paging();
        page.count(20);
        page.setPage(1);
        List<String> favList  =new ArrayList<String>();

        statuses =twitter.getHomeTimeline();      <----- error line

        for(Status status: statuses){
            favList.add("@"+status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
        }
        model.addAttribute("favList",favList);
    }


    return "/web/favList";
}
```

=====================================================================================================

error : Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-web] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details

at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:186)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1554)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getHomeTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:105)
    at web.controller.twitterTest.favList(twitterTest.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)